# jQuery Mobile Popup woes

Tags: jquery, mobile, popup

I have only just started using the new jQM 1.2 popup feature in any serious way and have run into numerous strange issues.  I need to open my popups from script not via a data-rel='popup' click.  "Easy", I thought - simply put in the popup element with data-role set to 'popup' and then open it from script as element.popup('open').  I tried that only to have jQM complaining

Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on popup prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'open'

So I thought I would simply not use the data-role at all, set the element style to display:none and then simply do

element.popup().css('display':'block').popup('open') from script where required.  This works like a charm the first time round.  Then when I try to reopen the popup nothing happens - no popup!  I thought this might have something to do with initializing the popup twice over so I changed my code to

```
if ('undefined' == typeof(element.data('ppp'))
element.popup().css('display','block').data('ppp',1);
```

followed by

```
element.popup('open')
```

Still no joy - it seems like the popup forgets its data attributes once it has been closed

Any help with this would be much appreciated - essentially all I want to do is to open and close popups several times over from script.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a very simple answer to this.  Attempting to access a popup element in order to open it by locating it via its dummy class declaration, ppp in this instance, will never work.  If you want to locate a popup you must give it an id.  No id, no way to get at the popup.  This becomes clear once you look at the code that jQM generates when it sees data-role='popup'.  In place of your original popup definition it leaves behind an empty DIV tag containing little more than

```
<div>
<!--Placeholder for popupid-->
<div>
```

At the bottom of the page where the popup was originally defined it puts in two new divs

```
<div class='ui-popup-screen ui-screen-hidden' id='popupid-screen'></div>
<div class='ui-popup-container ui-selectmenu-hidden' id='popupid-popup'>..</div>
```

All the contents of the originally defined popup get moved into this latter div.  Don't provide an id for the original popup and the mechanism for accessing it in any useful way via jQuery simply breaks down.